# How to show Ruby Rails Form Modal popup on button click?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When some one click on a **Add new** button in index.html.erb the form popup will show on this page the form date will come from new.html.erb so how I can do this I am using bootstrap.
Please any example.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, cpoy this modal code, it is official from bootsrap,

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Copy the modal from here and go to index.html.erb
Place a

```
<%= link_to (your_edit_path) do %>
# place modal here After inserting your required fields using form_for helper
<% end %>
```

now on the submit button rails will automatically send a post request to create action in your_controller. and boom, your task is done.
Do, let me know if you face any difficulty. I will help you in any case.